# Store data locally long term

Tags: python, numpy, storage, similarity

I am working on a reccommender algorithm for songs. I have a matrix of values that I get the cosine similiarity of in python ( numPy). The problem is that every time i run the program i need to recompute the similarity of every vector to every other vector. I want to store the results of computations locally so i don't have to compute it every time.

The first thing that comes to my mind is storing them in a text file, or in the database itself. Surely theres a better way though?

Comment: Take a look at the [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[numpy.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is what you need :

```
numpy.save(file, arr)
Save an array to a binary file in NumPy .npy format.
```

Comment: I'd have a 42,000 x 42000 result set. Would you save them in 42,000 seperate arrays?

Comment: [numpy.savez](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) allows you to save several arrays into a single file in uncompressed .npz format.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/joblib

It is made to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to answer you question. Because i don't know about ur data volume and type.
But i can tell you now.
If u are thinking about file for that, it may have scale out issue, if u scale out python server to # of box. So u may need a shared storage. In that case u have to think about shared storage file system like glusterFS or Hadoop. (glusterFS is more eaisier). But the access time will be very poor.
The other option is u can think about Redis. It is memory based key & value store. It also supports file persistance. (because of that it's characteristics is little different from memcahed.)
Final option is u can think about NoSQL which can support scalability and performance. But it is always depends on your requirement.